# Calculo de Datos en Python para obtener el producto mas vendido

Tags: python

Como puedo obtener la venta de productos para calcular el producto más vendido en el mes de enero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes filtrar los datos para obtener solo las filas correspondientes al mes de **Enero** y luego agrupar por **Producto** y sumar las **Ventas**.

```
# Filtrar por mes de enero y agrupar por Producto
ventas_enero = df[df['Mes'] == 'enero'].groupby('Producto')['Ventas'].sum()

# Obtener el producto más vendido en enero
producto_mas_vendido = ventas_enero.idxmax()

print('Producto:', producto_mas_vendido)
```

El método **idxmax()** para obtener el índice del máximo valor de ventas en enero, que corresponderá al producto más vendido.

Comment: Muchas Gracias te pasaste, lo voy a validar, grcias

Comment: Amigo y tuviera la fecha en este formato. como saco el mes  'Fecha': ['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04', '2022-01-05', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-02']

Comment: No he entendido la pregunta, es posible que puedas explicar más en detalle?

Comment: Gracias Xhamu, ya lo resolvi con la funcion pd.to_datetime(df['Fecha’]), muchas grcais